# Draft mode after include statements

Tags: graphics

Normally when I have a document with graphicx that I'd like to see rendered in `draft` mode I use:

```
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
```

However, assuming I've already called the line:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

How can I set the mode to draft after this point? Looking at the docs the best I came up with was this (unsuccessful) attempt:

```
\ExecuteOptions{draft}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[ ... ]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{draft}
[ ... ]
```

Comment: @Herbert Awesome! Why does `\PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{graphicx}` not work? I tried it and got `Option clash for package graphicx` (probably something to do with tikz).

Comment: @macmadness86: maybe it's too late. Provide an example.

Comment: @Herbert Yes it was added too late, however, put `\setkeys` in the same place and it works. I think this would warrant a new question. Understanding why `\setkeys{Gin}{draft}` works in places where `\PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{graphicx}` seems like it should be part of your answer here.