# Draft mode in Tikz externalize hides graphics, but not without externalize

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, draft

Maybe this is expected behaviour, but it's not documented in the manual, and it certainly surprised me.

When you use the `draft` class option and use the `tikz` `external` library, all Tikz pictures are replaced by a box with the name of the externalized graphic.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle [radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result with draft]

The fact that it displays the correct filename leads me to think it's the `external` library doing this, because whilst I know that `pgf` itself does a similar thing with the `draft` option, I wouldn't expect it to know the filename (and anyway, I haven't loaded `pgf` directly, and I think it only obeys `draft` when called directly.)

However, commenting out the `\tikzexternalize` line gives the picture.

[image: Result without draft]

I'm not saying that this behaviour wouldn't often be useful! However, it's not what I'd prefer in what I'm working on, and as it isn't documented I don't know what I can do about it.

I can try and work around it, and not use `draft` but it's in a big document that already does several different things depending on whether `draft` is set.

What are my options?

Comment: Why wouldn't you expect it to know the filenames?

Comment: `draft` mode effect graphics that included form external files, which is what `\tikzexternalize` does, and does not effect the `tikzpicture` environment as it is not a graphic that is included, but rather just some code that gets typeset.

Comment: I meant that I wouldn't expect the basic `pgf` to know the filenames of the externalized pictures (e.g. main-texfile-figure0), since they're generated by the `external` library. That wasn't very clear, I'll edit it.

Comment: @PeterGrill are you saying that the `external` library just replaces a `\begin{tikzpicture} \end{tikzpicture}` with `\includegraphics{name-of-file-built-by-external}` and that it's the just the `latex` core responding to the `draft` option?

That would make a lot of sense, and now I don't know why I didn't think of it! I suppose I was assuming that `external` did something more complicated.

Comment: @JosephCooper The complicated bit that `external` does is to create the graphic in the first place.  But once it is created then it is included back in via `\includegraphics` and what you are seeing is the effect of the `draft` option on the `graphicx` package.  However, I would say that this is definitely Not Obvious Behaviour and there's no reason why one would guess that (especially as `graphicx` is loaded via `pgf` so one might not know it was being used).

Comment: @PeterGrill You should write that as an answer.  Although when you know then the answer is simple, I wouldn't consider it an obvious thing to guess if you don't know so it's a useful question to have here, and therefore one that should be answered properly.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Thankyou for that extremely useful comment. It leads to another, related problem, which is that attempting to manually override the `draft` option for `graphicx` doesn't work. Using `\usepackage[final]{graphicx}` before `\usepackage{tikz}` does nothing, and after gives an option clash for `graphicx`.

Comment: Try using Herbert's answer to this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9751/86 only with `final` instead of `draft`.  Do this after loading `tikz` and don't load `graphicx` yourself - let `tikz` do that.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Done. Hope I covered all the basis.

Comment: @AndrewStacey I saw that, but greping the graphics directory, it looks like there's only a `draft` key, no `final` (which corresponds with the error message). I think I'll make this a new question actually. I think this one's been answered now.

Answer (score 14):

There is a "fix" for the underlying problem as proposed by [Christian](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53289/tikz-externalize-in-draft-mode#comment127444_53289)s comment:

TikZ does **not** use `\includegraphics` for externalized figures as stated in the documentation but `\pgfimage{figure0.eps}`. This is not aware of the draft mode. 
This can be changed in the beginning of the document with

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/images/include external/.code=\includegraphics{#1}}
```

leading to

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/images/include external/.code=\includegraphics{#1}}

\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle [radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which renders the "draft-box" for the missing image in the correct size.

Comment: Better late than never! This answer is definitely the answer to the concrete question. I load my `graphicx` package with the "final" option, as I do not wish to have blanks for images - I use draft mode to change margins and to show fixme annotations.

Comment: Does someone know if this should work with XeTeX? I have some problems here.

Answer (score 13):

### Documentclass `[draft]` option:

Using the optional parameter `[draft]` to the `\documentclass` has two main uses:

- indicate overfull hbox by a vertical bar in the margin
- graphics that are included from *external* sources do not get displayed (only an outline of the box is displayed).  A similar effect can be achieved using `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`.

This has no effect on the `tikzpicture` environment within a document as that is not considered an external graphic. Its content is typeset and displayed in the output, just as the content of any other environment would be.

### TikZ Externalization Library:

The main purpose of `\usetikzlibrary[external]` and the associated `\tikzexternalize` is to speed up compile times by converting each `tikzpicture` into a separate *external* graphic which is then imported with `\includegraphics`.  Hence, the behavior you are seeing.

This can be disabled on a per use basis by using `\tikzexternaldisable` within a group:

```
{\tikzexternaldisable% disable within a group
\begin{tikzpicture}
  ...
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

or disabling externalization before the `tikzpicture` and re-enabling it following the picture:

```
\tikzexternaldisable% disable outside of a group
\begin{tikzpicture}
  ...
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikzexternalenable% should re-enable at end.
```

Disabling will probably be required for cases where there are nested `tikzpicture` environments.

The MWE example below illustrates these and yields:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}

{\tikzexternaldisable% disable within a group
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [blue, ultra thick, fill=red!10] (0,0) circle [radius=1] node {1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\tikzexternaldisable% disbale outside of a group
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [red, ultra thick, fill=blue!10] (0,0) circle [radius=1] node {2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\tikzexternalenable% should renable at end.

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [black, ultra thick,fill=yellow!20] (0,0) circle [radius=1] node {3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```