# Tikz externalize in draft mode

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

This is a follow-up to [Draft mode in Tikz externalize hides graphics, but not without externalize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47444/draft-mode-in-tikz-externalize-hides-graphics-but-not-without-externalize)

I'm writing a long document and compilation takes time. Some plots are included as tikz (export from matlab2tikz) and other images are simply included with `\includegraphics`. 
I'm using the latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf workflow.
For speedup, the document is in draft mode (most often, I'm not interested in seeing all images). For tikz speedup the externalization works fine.

However, as explained in [Draft mode in Tikz externalize hides graphics, but not without externalize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47444/draft-mode-in-tikz-externalize-hides-graphics-but-not-without-externalize), the tikz-draft results in small boxes. The original figure size seems lost and the document starts to move around quite a bit.

I get the warnings:

```
Package pgf Warning: Missing width for image "pgflastimage" ("images/tikz/figure8") in draft mode.
(pgf)                Using 1cm instead on input line 980.

Package pgf Warning: Missing height for image "pgflastimage" ("images/tikz/figure8") in draft mode.
(pgf)                Using 1cm instead on input line 980.
```

and the result is just a small box. It looks like it is trying to find the correct box size and fails. Is there a workaound or fix for this bug?

My externalization is done by

```
\tikzset{external/system call={latex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error 
-interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource" &&
dvips -o "\image".ps "\image".dvi && ps2eps "\image".ps;}}
```

which generates good .eps images.
The generated images are fine and the box would be of the correct size, when included manually with `\includegraphics{figure0.eps}`.

---

Here is an approach for a possible hack. At first, I included my figures with `\subimport{path}{filename.tikz}`
which helps with sub-directories, based on the package `import`.

Based on this idea I began to replace this import with `\tikzimport{path}{filename.tikz}` containing

```
\newcommand{\tikzimport}[2]{%
\ifdraft{%
  % create counter, increment
  \newstepcounter{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/external/figure name}}%
  % define next filename of externalized tikz file
  \def\mynextfile{images/tikz/%
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/external/figure name}%
  \arabic{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/external/figure name}}.eps}%
  % check is file is there, then includegraphics the file
  % as we are in draft, this gives a nice box
  \IfFileExists{\mynextfile}{% show tikz
  \includegraphics[scale=1]{\mynextfile}}{% fallback
  \mbox{\nolinkurl{\mynextfile}}
}
}{% nodraft
  \subimport{#1}{#2}%
}
```

This requires the `ifdraft` package and a counter for each `figure name` suffix. Creating a counter (if it does not exist) is achieved by

```
\makeatletter
\def\newstepcounter#1{%
\@ifundefined{c@#1}{%
\newcounter{#1}}{%
\stepcounter{#1}}%
}
\makeatother
```

**Problems**

- This is not really nice ...
- the tikz externalized prefix is hardcoded, I have no idea how to extract the prefix from the tikz internals. The prefix is set by `\tikzexternalize[prefix=images/tikz/]` but `\pgfkeys{/tikz/external/prefix}` comes back empty
- I have a few graphics not being externalized, as they come back wrong if externalized. It would be good to test for each call, if externalization is enabled for each graph.

I tired

```
\newif\isexternal
\pgfkeys{/tikz/external/export/.is if=isexternal}
\isexternal
  external
\else
  not external
\fi
```

But this test comes back false all the time.

Comment: TikZ uses `\pgfimage{figure0.eps}` to include the external graphics. And `\pgfimage` has some deficiancies... perhaps you can use `\pgfkeys{/pgf/images/include external/.code=\includegraphics{#1}}` to fix your issue... (untested at the time of this writing)