# Draft option in TikZ like graphicx

Tags: tikz-pgf

We know the use of [draft] in **graphicx** package

```
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
```

Do we have any option like [draft] in **tikz**? Sothat we need not compile the tikz picture for every run and need not look at the picture...Is it possible to have something like this?

```
\usepackage[draft]{tikz}
```

or **do i have any other method to do it?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `\tikzexternalize` which is intended to speed up compile times.  It converts each `tikzpicture` into a separate *external* graphic which is then imported with `\includegraphics`.  And in `[draft]` mode graphics that are included from *external* sources do not get displayed.

Here is an example of enabling `\tikzexternalize` when in `[draft]` mode.
With `\documentclass[draft]{article}` the MWE produces:

[image]

### References:

- [Draft mode in Tikz externalize hides graphics, but not without externalize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47444/draft-mode-in-tikz-externalize-hides-graphics-but-not-without-externalize).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifdraft}

\usepackage{tikz}
\ifoptionfinal{}{%
    \usetikzlibrary{external}\tikzexternalize
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill=yellow] (0,0) -- (3,0) -- (3,3) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't really work here for me: `! Package tikz Warning: The key 'up to date check=md5' is impossible, there is no macro to compute MD5. Falling back to 'up to date check=diff'. ===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'xelatex -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tikzext-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{tikzext}\input{tikzext}"' ========`

Comment: @buhtz: I am guessing but I think you just need to delete the temporary files an re-run. If that does not solve your problem, I'd suggest you post a new question.

Comment: @PeterGrill What if the graphics are `standalone` files?

Comment: @Casimir: It should still work, AFAIK. If not, please ask a new question and include a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem and reference this question.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks for the offer. I ended up using `\usepackage[subpreambles=true,mode=buildnew]{standalone}` which (with shell escape enabled) builds all `standalone` files into PDFs _once_ (unless any modifications were made and detected by `mode=buildnew` in which case they are rebuilt) and inserts these using `\includegraphics`. This considerably cuts down on compilation time.