# TikZ: How to use \tikzexternalize in TeXstudio or How to create Makefile for using \tikzexternalize

Tags: tikz-pgf

This question is based on  [Draft option in TikZ like graphicx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59530/draft-option-in-tikz-like-graphicx).

From pgf manual,

> 33.4 Externalizing Graphics
>
> The probably most comfortable way is to use the default conguration
> with **pdflatex -shell-escape main** which authorizes pdflatex to call
> itself recursively to generate the images.

Also manual says *"users will need to issue the required commands manually (or with make)"*

How to issue the required commands manually?

or

How to issue the required commands using makefile?

I am using **TeXstudio** with **Miktex**

Answer (score 2):

All this means is that in a Makefile or similar you need to remember to put

```
pdflatex --shell-escape <filename>
```

rather than just

```
pdflatex <filename>
```

Of course, you might have this as a variable in you Makefile to allow flexibility.