# Problem with many tikz picture for every rendering

Tags: tikz-pgf, environment-variables, rendering

> I have many tikz picture in my text, and for every rendering of LATEX, I waste hours to external pdf is produced. If there is a way to define **samples=100** as a variable, (like var1:=100 in programming) in main tex file to set it with for example '5' and when I want to obtain final pdf file, set sample with 100.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Maybe the following can help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59533/124842

Comment: I tried that with a small part, It takes the same time (approximately)

Comment: Related [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184454/managing-texts-with-many-tikz-pictures).

Comment: you can use tikz externalize to just render pre-made tikz pictures or simply use conditional code to not typeset them at all in drafts.

Comment: @MyGlasses But if you try with your entire document, is there still no improvement?

Comment: @MyGlasses using tikz externalize and draft mode takes the same time (after the first run) then the time is being taken by doing something other than tikz, as externalize means that after the first run and the image is saved, the tikz code isn't run at all.

Comment: How does tikz externalize know that you haven't changed your parameters since the last run?  Anyway, you can also use standalone to save the images and \includegraphics to show them.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I am trying to do your first question, and I think you are right, I though about that problem. But about second sentence,  I can't convert all picture to files. and thanks.

Comment: @MyGlasses That is what externalisation does, too. This is the standard approach. Why on Earth can't you use it? Note that if you switch to externalisation, your first run will take *longer* to compile. But subsequent runs will be much faster. If they aren't then either you got errors when compiling or it isn't the Ti*k*Z code taking the time. Note that `pgfplots` has its own specialist externalisation facilities.