# How can I set the 'final' option for the graphicx package in XeTeX?

Tags: graphics, xetex, package-options, option-clash

I'm using XeTeX and wondering how to set the `final` option of the `graphicx` package.

I started my document with pdfTeX and the following lines:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, headsepline, draft]{scrreprt}

...

\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
```

Then I migrated to XeTeX and got an option clash for the `graphicx` package. Having removed the `graphicx` declaration the clash vanished but so did the graphics.
Doing some research I came across [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9751/draft-mode-after-include-statements) and tried to change it from `draft` to `final` but unfortunately without success.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In particular, those two lines alone give no error, so there must be something else causing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not completely clear what your problem is. The `scrreprt` class does not load the `graphicx` package so

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{mill.png}
\end{document}
```

should work without problems. It is likely that you are loading another package that loads the `graphicx` package. For example, you get an option clash error with

```
\documentclass[draft]{beamer}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{mill.png}
\end{document}
```

because `beamer` loads `graphicx` and gives it the `draft` option. There are at least three ways around this problem. The first is to use `\PassOptionsToPackage` prior to loading the class to pass the `final` option to `graphicx`

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{final}{graphicx}
\documentclass[draft]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{mill.png}
\end{document}
```

The second option is to set the "draft" flag in graphicx to false directly

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\Gin@draftfalse
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{mill.png}
\end{document}
```

The third option is to set the "draft" flag in graphicx to false with `\setkeys`

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{draft=false}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{mill.png}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you can pass options to package which are loaded inside classes by using `\PassOptionsToPackage{<options>}{<package>}` before `\documentclass`. However, I'm not sure about the order between these and class options, so you might end up with `final,draft` resulting in `draft` because the latest option, i.e. the most right one, will prevail.

Comment: `\setkeys{Gin}{draft=false}` seems cleaner than having to `\makeatother`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer, yes that is also an option and in this case doesn't seem to result in order issues.

Comment: @akim you are correct, that is a lot cleaner. I didn't know about the `\setkeys` method.